# Populate an excel sheet with data from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a word document, which looks like this:

```
Customer name: _____

Customer ID: _____

[Button] "Click here to add another customer"
```

Users will fill in the customer name and customer ID.

I have a separate excel workbook. It looks like this:

```
Customer Name:

Customer ID:
```

I want to add a button on the Excel sheet: When I press the button, a pop up box will appear, asking me From which file I want to extract data from. I will select the word document, and the Excel sheet will be auto populated from the data in the Word document.

I have tried experimenting with Word's Quickparts -> fields -> database. But I only managed to extract data from excel into the word document.

How should I approach this problem? Any functions I am missing?

Comment: Look into [file pickers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219843(v=office.11).aspx) with .doc* file mask to list only Word documents. Capture the user the selection and pass that to the code which opens the Word document. Then, depending on what you actually want to transfer from the Word doc try [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=copying+text+from+word+to+excel&oq=Copying+text+from+word&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.7006j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and see which options suit. Post back with code and any specific problems.

Comment: Opening Word from Excel https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d543bf7f-49f0-4192-a050-e582ed47ced2/opening-a-word-document-from-an-excel-vba-module?forum=isvvba

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take values from Word to Excel using the button in the Excel spreadsheet, you need to control Word from Excel. There are two ways, early and late binding. Early binding is easier, so let's begin with it. 
In Excel VBA editor, click Tools menu, then open References. Find Microsoft Word XX Object Library and tick it. You can now use Word controls in Excel VBA Editor.

Declare variables:

```
Sub DateFromWord()

Dim appW As Word.Application
Dim ADoc As Document
Dim ph As Paragraph
Dim strR(1) As String
Dim i As Integer
```

and then set ADoc as your *opened* Word document.

```
Set appW = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set ADoc = ActiveDocument
```

This is very simple way. I have assumed that you have only one Word document and you have it opened. It would be more sophisticated if you wanted to choose docs from file or something. But you have asked how to approach the problem, not the tailored solution, haven't you?

Then you may loop through paragraphs in your document.

```
For Each ph In ADoc.Paragraphs
  'Do something
Next ph
```

What you should to inside the loop? My suggestion is to check, if there is ":" in the paragraph. If it is, then before it you have either "custoemr id" or "customer name" and after it you have actual name or id. The loop should be like this:

```
For Each ph In ADoc.Paragraphs
    If InStr(ph.Range, ":") Then
        For i = 0 To 1
            strR(i) = Split(ph.Range, ":")(i)
        Next i
        Debug.Print strR(0) & "    " & strR(1)
    End If
Next ph
```

Instead of debug.print you should put values in cells of the Excel or do whatever you want with those string. Any questions?

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this with Rich Text Content Control as the user input in Word, so that I can directly reference the RTCC object instead of having to loop through paragraphs to detect where user input begins and ends. (Would this be a smarter way to approach the problem?) Will update when I encounter troubles.